# Most performant way to Insert or Read(if record already exists) in Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Assuming I have a `cars` table where `vin` is the primary key.
I want to insert a record(in a transaction) or read the record(if one already exists with the same PK).

**What's the most performant way to insert the record or read it if one already exists with the same PK?**

This is my current approach:

**Case A:** Record does not exist

1. Insert record
2. Return record

**Case B:** Record already exists

1. Insert record
2. Check if error is due to the record already existing
3. Read the record
4. Return record

```
const car = { vin: '123', make: 'honda', model: 'accord' };

spannerDatabase.runTransactionAsync(async (databaseTransaction) => {
    try {
        // Try to insert car
        await databaseTransaction.insert('cars', car);
        await databaseTransaction.commit();
        return car;
    } catch (error) {
        await databaseTransaction.end();
        // Spanner "row already exists" error. Insert failed because there is already a record with the same vin(PK)
        if (error.code === 6) {
            // Since the record already exists, I want to read it and return it. Whats the most performant way to do this?
            const existingRecord = await carsTable.read({
                columns: ['vin', 'make', 'model'],
                keys: [car.vin],
                json: true,
            });
            return existingRecord;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I think that's a perfect way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Just a minor nit on the insert, you could use the mutation API ([example](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/nodejs#write-data-with-mutations)) to avoid having to pass a transaction around and avoid the `commit()` call.

But if you ever need to change your code to read your own writes (RYW) then you'll have to use a DML query within a transaction as [RYW is not supported with the mutations API](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-versus-mutations#feature_comparison_between_dml_and_mutations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @skuruppu mentioned in the comment above, your current example is mostly fine for what you are describing. It does however implicitly assume a couple of things, as you are not executing the read and the insert in the same transaction. That means that the two operations together are not atomic, and other transactions might update or delete the record between your two operations.

Also, your approach assumes that scenario A (record does not exist) is the most probable. If that is not the case, and it is just as probable that the record **does exist**, then you should execute the read in the transaction before the write.

You should also do that if there are other processes that might delete the record. Otherwise, another process might delete the record **after** you tried to insert the record, but **before** you try to read it (outside the transaction).

The above is only really a problem **if** there are other processes that might delete or alter the record. If that is not the case, and also won't be in the future, this is only a theoretical problem.

So to summarize:

1. Your example is fine **if** scenario A is the most probable **and** no other process will ever delete any records in the `cars` table.
2. You should execute the read before the write using the same read/write transaction for both operations if any of the conditions in 1 are not true.

The `read` operation that you are using in your example is the most efficient way to read a single row from a table.